# Signing message have prefix?

Tags: polkadot-js, signing, apps

I would like to know if when signing messages through Polkadot-JS it adds a prefix to the message before the signing to avoid signing transactions.

Do we have different functions for signing messages and transactions? Or they are the same and the validation of whether it is a transaction or not should be done on client-side?

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't add a prefix.

But signing messages and transactions do use separate functions.

The [Signer interface](https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/blob/977eb3f9ecb8a2fb57b46b7da7f797b56a9e8bf2/packages/types/src/types/extrinsic.ts#L135-L150) is defined as:

```
export interface Signer
  /**
   * @description signs an extrinsic payload from a serialized form
   */
  signPayload?: (payload: SignerPayloadJSON) => Promise<SignerResult>;

  /**
   * @description signs a raw payload, only the bytes data as supplied
   */
  signRaw?: (raw: SignerPayloadRaw) => Promise<SignerResult>;

  /**
   * @description Receives an update for the extrinsic signed by a `signer.sign`
   */
  update?: (id: number, status: H256 | ISubmittableResult) => void;
}
```

When signing messages, `signRaw` is called. When signing transactions, `signPayload` is used.

If you call `alice.sign('a')` to sign a message, the payload would always be like

```
{
  type: "bytes",
  data: "a",
  address: "15StioR7cW1cui19icpxivT6iZR6e9RFKtj2urou1opJsCms"
}
```

But the result will vary each time you call it, because in sr25519 signatures are non-deterministic.

When you call `await api.tx.system.remark('a')`, the payload will be like

```
{
  specVersion: "0x0000240e",
  transactionVersion: "0x0000000c",
  address: "15StioR7cW1cui19icpxivT6iZR6e9RFKtj2urou1opJsCms",
  blockHash: "0x00b2aa61d007c887d20050856c9fd98d649dd92dda14eedc2faea189dfac05ad",
  blockNumber: "0x00a6409f",
  era: "0xf501",
  genesisHash: "0x91b171bb158e2d3848fa23a9f1c25182fb8e20313b2c1eb49219da7a70ce90c3",
  method: "0x00011448656c6c6f",
  nonce: "0x00000000",
  signedExtensions: [
    "CheckNonZeroSender",
    "CheckSpecVersion",
    "CheckTxVersion",
    "CheckGenesis",
    "CheckMortality",
    "CheckNonce",
    "CheckWeight",
    "ChargeTransactionPayment",
    "PrevalidateAttests"
  ],
  tip: "0x00000000000000000000000000000000",
  version: 4
}
```

The two types of payloads are not compatible with each other. Therefore you cannot send a spoofed transaction that way.

Comment: I see if the default behavior is not to add a prefix. This would mean that if we are using an external tool to sign a message that is not polkadot-js. It will follow the same pattern and not add a prefix as well. That means this tool could be signing a valid transaction since it will not add a prefix. I guess we will have to add some kind of validation to check if what was sent to sign is not a transaction. Would we have to decode the whole data and try to fit it into the transaction metadata to see if it is a valid transaction or not?